# Run process A continuously and process B for X minutes per day, never at the same time

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a requirement where I need to run a process (we'll call it Process A) 24/7, except for X (configurable) number of minutes a day where I need to run a different process (we'll call this Process B).

Process A is configured to start when windows boots, in the case of any outages etc.

Process B needs to run for X minutes a day, and take priority over Process A. This needs to be handled on restarts, outages, etc. The processes can never run at the same time, and I don't have access to the source code of either process, so the "lifecycle" will have to be managed by something else.

What approach might you use to manage this structure?

Must run on windows 10.

Comment: Have process B stop and restart process A?

Comment: put them both into PowerShell jobs and just use Suspend-Job -job Process A when process B needs to run